# The number of permutations of finite set that keep at least one element fixed

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Find the number of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ that keep at least one integer
fixed.

---

**Progress**. First I consider only one integer is fixed then the number of permutations of the other 4 integers is 4!, i.e, 24. Next I consider 2 integers fixed. The number of permutations in this case is 2!3!, i.e., 12 and so on. I'm getting 76 as the final answer. Is this correct?

Comment: First I consider only one integer is fixed then the number of permutations of the other 4 integers is 4!,i.e, 24.next i consider 2 integers fixed. The number of permutations in this case is 2!3!,i.e., 12 and so on. I'm getting 76 as the final answer. Is this correct?